# Alpha channel not working

Tags: c#, xaml, alpha

So I am writing a basic app for the windows phone but the alpha channel doesn't seem to be showing up in any of the images I use.  In Fireworks I can see the alpha channel in there.

```
<Image Source="Assets/Images/OnBar.png" Width="100" Height="60" Margin="280, -560, 0, 0" />
```

That is the xaml code used to display the image in the first place.  Currently I don't have any C# code behind it so if I need to implement something on that side a point to the right direction would be appreciated.  I looked around but couldn't find anything that worked or was useful.  The Image itself is also white so if the alpha channel doesn't work then nothing will display.  Any help is appreciated.

Comment: where to you put this image? is it on a control, like a button or something? consider making the background transparent, but anyway do tell more.

Comment: the image itself is not a button, its just a normal images placed into the window with no functionality.  The only thing I can give of its location would be the fact that its located in the main grid of the window.  As for the background I made it transparent through the fireworks editor but it still doesn't show like that in the actual window.  Its not only this image its any image I load.  I am thinking there is something I am forgetting to declare in the image parameters but can't figure out what it is.

Answer (score 0):

Just tested it, it works fine with an arbitrary transparent `Image`. Maybe your png export format isn't compatible with xaml. Or your `Image`is inside a container which isn't  transparent.

But you don't forget to declare anything in `Image`'s parameters, alpha channel is built-in and no tweakable, as far as I know.

Please provide more details and I'll edit my post.

Comment: The issue was within fireworks and not the actual code.  Even thought I set the entire image to have the background an alpha channel I never went into the modify settings and set the background color to transparent.